# How to move a h5 element to the top left within a div?

Tags: html, css

I am developing a visual presentation in D3.js that will serve as a feedback system for my athletes. I am trying to get the static text (that is, BIB LOYPE and TID) to appear in the top left corner of the box and the dynamic text (that is, 3, 3, 8), rendered every 3rd second, in the middle of the box. How can I accomplish this using CSS?
[image]

This is my HTML code. As you see I have tried to create an id on the h5 element, which didn't work.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header"><h1>LIVE RESULTATER</h1><br></div>
        <div class="bib"><h5>BIB:</h5><br></div>
        <div class="loype"><h5 id="resultatfremvisning">LOYPE:</h5><br></div>
        <div class="resultat"><h5>TID:</h5></div>
        <div class="footer">@cmagelssen - </div>
    </div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #b1dfe6;
            margin: 10px;
            font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
            
        }

        .container {
        color: black;
        height: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 3px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: 40px auto 400px 40px;
        grid-template-areas: 
            "h h h h h h h h h h h h"
            "b b b b b b l l l l l l"
            "r r r r r r r r r r r r"
            "f f f f f f f f f f f f";
            }
            .container div {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            color:black;
        }


        .header {
            grid-area: h;
        }

        .bib {
            grid-area: b;
            border-radius: 6px;
            background-color: white;
            font-size: 4em;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 3px;
            
        }

        .loype {
            grid-area: l;
            border-radius: 6px;
            background-color: white;
            font-size: 4em;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 3px;
        }

        .resultat {
            grid-area: r;
            border-radius: 6px;
            background-color: white;
            font-size: 7em;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 3px;
            text-align: left,
        }
        #resultatfremvisning {
            text-align: left,
        }
        .footer {
            grid-area: f;
        }


    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to that h5 element or just target h5 in general in your styles.css file, and use the text align css rule and set it to left.
What I mean:

```
h5 {
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: another way is if you just make the position relative and then do left: whatever many pixels you want it to go to the left

Answer (score 1):

I show code, please apply below code in CSS.

```
.resultat h5, 
.loype h5
{
    margin-right: auto;
}
```